# Pointers in c: Function which deletes every second element of linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I want to write a function which gets a pointer to a header of a linked list and deletes from the list every second member of it. The List is a linked elements of type *element*:

```
typedef struct element{
    int num;
    struct element* next;
}element;
```

I'm new to all these pointers arithmetic so I'm not sure I write it correctly:

```
 void deletdscnds(element* head) {
    element* curr;
    head=head->next; //Skipping the dummy head//

    while (head!=NULL) {
        if (head->next==NULL) 
            return;

            else {
                curr=head;
                head=head->next->next; //worst case I'll reach NULL and not a next of a null//
                curr->next=head;
            }
        }
    }
```

I kept changing it since I kept finding errors. Can you please point out any possible errors?

Comment: Yikes! After you do that for a while you'll be standing knee-deep in leaked memory! You haven't deleted anything there...you've just lost it.

Comment: Should I just use 'free' function before I let it go?

Comment: You have to get the value of curr->next before you delete curr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The algorithm is a lot simpler if you think of your linked list in terms of node pairs. Each iteration of your loop should process two nodes - `head` and `head->next`, and leave `head` equal to `head->next->next` upon exit. It is also important to not forget deleting the middle node, if you are cutting it out of the list, otherwise you are going to see memory leaks.

```
while (head && head->next) {
    // Store a pointer to the item we're about to cut out
    element *tmp = head->next;
    // Skip the item we're cutting out
    head->next = head->next->next;
    // Prepare the head for the next iteration
    head = head->next;
    // Free the item that's no longer in the list
    free(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be most straightforward to visualize this problem in recursive terms, like this:

```
// outside code calls this function; the other functions are considered private
void deletdscnds(element* head) {
  delete_odd(head);
}

// for odd-numbered nodes; this won't delete the current node
void delete_odd(element* node) {
  if (node == NULL)
    return; // stop at the end of the list
  // point this node to the node two after, if such a node exists
  node->next = delete_even(node->next);
}

// for even-numbered nodes; this WILL delete the current node
void delete_even(element* node) {
  if (node == NULL)
    return NULL; // stop at the end of the list
  // get the next node before you free the current one, so you avoid
  // accessing memory that has already been freed
  element* next = node->next;
  // free the current node, that it's not needed anymore
  free(node);
  // repeat the process beginning with the next node
  delete_odd(next);
  // since the current node is now deleted, the previous node needs
  // to know what the next node is so it can link up with it
  return next;
}
```

For me, at least, this helps clarify what needs to be done at each step.

I wouldn't advise actually using this method because, in C, recursive algorithms may take up a lot of RAM and cause stack overflows with compilers that don't optimize them. Rather, dasblinkenlight's answer has the code that you should actually use.